# Is there a name for this type of connection?

Tags: conductivity, conductors

I can't think of a time when I've encountered this, but I think that this is a thing: you have two conductive paths that, when connected, become one path. How they become connected is through tension/compression: they press against each other such that the metal of each path is still elastic. Ideally, this would allow something else to be inserted between the two paths that would still allow them to be conductive and the metal still elastic.

[image: Crude sketch of electrical connection (with and without other object inserted between.]

Is there a name for this sort of connection?

(Bonus question: would/could this sort of connection be viable as a four-way connection?)

Comment: Aren't they connected through compression rather than tension. If not then I can't imagine what you mean = time to make a picture! At the moment I'm visualizing a jack socket (with auxiliary contacts) and plug but I'm sure it's a million miles from this.

Comment: you mean a *press contact*? Maybe a *spring-loaded contact*? A *spring contact*?

Comment: It sounds like a switch of some sort.  A sketch might help, here.

Comment: looks like a modified `card edge connector` ... also similar to a modified `knife blade switch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very common in what is called a shorting jack.  1/4" and 1/8" phone jacks often have switch contacts that are moved apart or together when the plug is inserted.  Usually the plug is breaking a connection rather than maintaining it, but it can be wired either way.

This also is common in power input jacks for something that has internal batteries plus an external wall wart power source.

Additional comment:  Plugging a pin in between separable contacts that maintains the connection between the contacts is nothing more than plugging a pin into a socket.  If the electrical relationship between the two contacts is the same with or without the pin inserted, then no switching is going on.

Comment: Based on what you said and a google search, is something like either II or VI in this pdf (https://www.switchcraft.com/documents/jack_schematics.pdf) what I'm looking for?

Comment: Oh, wait, I think the audio/power input jack might be what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Probably.  See the additional comment.

Comment: The idea that I have is I'm trying to detect when specific, unique components are inserted into a data line. If nothing is inserted, then it's just a conductive path; if the component is inserted, then data can be read.

Comment: Oh, and the circuit in mind is an 8x8 grid, so I'm trying to avoid having 64 GPIO pins.